# simply loading a view based on what page the current UIPageControl is on

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to have a UIPageControl in my app but each page has complex content that would take hours and hours to do programatically. So my question is whether I can make an array that will hold the names of all my XIB Files with different views and simply load them based on what page the user is?

And if anyone has any insight to what methods need to be used to this, it would be much appreciated. I already know all the UIPageControl functions, I am just confused on things like [addsubview subview:one] for example...

Thanks!

EDIT

with that being said I have a UIViewController called *AreaViewController. UIPageControl is in another UIViewController called *simpleViewController. I have imported "areaViewController.h" within simpleViewController.h. From there I have declared IBOutlet AreaViewController *testing1;

Now within simpleViewController.m, I do this within one of the methods (From this point I know the UIPageControl works because I have tested it with simple things like colors on each page)

[scrollView addSubview:testing1.view]; //So when page 1 of UIPageControl loads, it would be the view of AreaViewController. This crashes on me... any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Any information on the crash? What is the exception/stack? Enable Zombie Objects for more information. My initial assumption without enough information is that `testing1` was released, you need to retain your controllers of the views that you add to your scrollview.

Comment: @Chris Wagner 2011-12-07 02:05:33.241 TabbedCalculation[2422:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ScrollingViewController 0x173bb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key simple.'
*** First throw call stack:

terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Looks like something is trying to set a property called `simple` on your `ScrollingViewController` class but it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

UIPageControl is used in conjunction with UIScrollView, UIScrollView is simply a view that extends beyond the viewport. It also has a paging attribute that you set to YES in order to get the snap-to paging effect you are looking for.

With that said, you are required to layout your views on this large horizontally spanning view  inside your UIScrollView.

For visual purposes consider the following

`|______|_|______|`<-- this is your scroll view's content, `| |` represents the device's screen/viewport

You are required to layout your views on that large view so that when it is scrolled your view becomes visible, so lets layout some views...

`[1_2_3_4_5_|6|_7_8_9_0]`

In this case our scroll view has 10 views laid out on its content area and view number 6 is visible to our user on their device. Now where did view 6 come from? The likely case is that the developer created a UIViewController or UIView and added it as a subview to the scrollview's content area and set it's position accordingly so it sits in the 6th position.

So with that said it should make you aware that if you create a view or view controller with interface builder, you can easily programmatically initialize that view/controller, and then add its view as a subview to the UIScrollView.

Now there is a lot more involved with managing the scrollview but I hope that clears up the concept for you.

Try not to confuse yourself too much and just realize that the UIScrollView is just a very large view that doesn't fit in the viewport, you can add whatever subviews you want to that view just like you normally would on any other UIView that is entirely visible.

**EDIT**

Also keep memory considerations in mind, you may need to do some tricky things if your views are incredibly complex and laying them all out at once is not feasible. You might have a situation where you only ever have 3 views laid out, one to the left, one visible, and one to the right. When the user scrolls one direction, say the left, you do some behind the scenes work to drop the extra view on the right, make the left view now the center view, and then create a new view that is now the left most.

Now visually...

`[4|5|6]` user swipes to see the left view (4), reconstruct your scrollview so it looks like so `[3|4|5]`

Comment: Thank you Chris. Much appreciated. I have edited my originally question with another similar question if you know how to do that by any chance. Thanks!